# Error occurred while locating signing assets

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufjnw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufjnw.png)

Error occurred while locating signing assets
I've been getting this error for a few days, I couldn't solve it in any way. I made sure that my ios account is active and problem-free and there is no problem with payment, but the error never went away, it would be great if you could help, thank you

Comment: Did you try to put your signing key in the keychain again?

Comment: How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that very same issue not too long ago. Lucky for us, the fix is a walk in the park. Just head on over to the App Store Connect website, sign in, and give that agreement a friendly nod. Voila, problem solved!